# DB2 concat column to result of substrin with xmlagg

Tags: sql, xml, db2, aggregate

I'm using `xmlagg` to do a `GROUP CONCAT` of a column. I'm then using `substr` on it.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(',' || COL1 || COL2)) as VARCHAR(1024)), 0) AS "foo"  FROM TABLE WHERE COL4 IN (100,200);
```

Now, I'd like to then prefix the result of the substr with the Value of the `IN` `COL4` (so either 100,200).

Doing

```
SELECT COL4 || SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(',' || COL1 || COL2)) as VARCHAR(1024)), 0) AS "foo"  FROM TABLE WHERE COL4 IN (100,200);
```

yields an error of `[SQL0122] Column COL4 or expression in SELECT list not valid.`

Interestingly enough, prefixing this with a generic string does work though,
ie.

```
SELECT 'bar' || SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(',' || COL1 || COL2)) as VARCHAR(1024)), 0) AS "foo"  FROM TABLE WHERE COL4 IN (100,200);
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the `xmlagg` and that the system doesn't know which `COL4` I'm referring to when I try to prefix the result.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try `char (col4)` in concatenation instead.

Comment: I get the same error trying `char(col4)` and `varchar(col4)`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read your example carefully. XMLAGG is an aggregate function, and you try to use `COL4` in the SELECT list without using it in the GROUP BY clause. Such a use is not correct.

Comment: No worries and thanks, I figured it was due to something like that. Is there any way I can "introduce" `COL4` inside the `GROUP BY` (but not actually return the actual string as a result of SUBSTR)...so that I can then use it in the Prefix?

Comment: Consider the following [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8c5568565faff5679c727f8bd264de13). The base table has 2 (col1, col2, col4) rows: ('A', 'B', 100), ('C', 'D', 400). What's the exact result you are going to get on this data?

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thanks so much for giving a clarifying example. I was led astray because with my data `IN (100, 400)`...only `100||400` will exist as COL4. 

So I'm looking for something like, "get this agg string where COL4 is either '100' or '400'...and then prefix that (100|400) to the result agg.

Comment: Why can't you use the corresponding string constant for such a concatenation?

Comment: You're saying to just prefix the string literal `"100"` or `"400"`? My problem is that I don't know if the match will be on the `100` or `400` in the `IN`

Comment: Strange question... Aren't you able to construct the corresponding query dynamically either parameterized or with constants? Please, edit your question with a couple of data examples and exact result desired on each one. It would be easier to help then...